# Propagate value from children with tidygraph

Tags: r, tidyverse, dendrogram, ggraph, tidygraph

I have a tree annotated at genus level (ie each leaf has a name) and I want to propagate the color of the leaves in the branches/edges as long as the children have the same genus, like in this plot:

[image]

[Source](http://www.data-imaginist.com/2017/Introducing-tidygraph/)

My tree is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwP-Rc1niAC3NUtjaFZGcVJ1Ylk/view?usp=sharing) (sorry, `dput` doesn't work...) and he looks like that:

```
library(ggraph)
library(tidygraph)
load("tree_v3")

TBL %>% activate(nodes) %>% as_tibble
# A tibble: 50 x 2
    leaf      Genus
   <lgl>     <fctr>
 1 FALSE         NA
 2  TRUE Klebsiella
 3  TRUE Klebsiella
 4 FALSE         NA
 5  TRUE Klebsiella
 6  TRUE Klebsiella
 7 FALSE         NA
 8 FALSE         NA
 9  TRUE Klebsiella
10 FALSE         NA
# ... with 40 more rows
```

I can print the tree with this code but as you can see, the edge colors stay near the leaves.

```
TBL %>%
  ggraph('dendrogram') + 
  theme_bw() +
  geom_edge_diagonal2(aes(color = node.Genus)) +
  scale_edge_color_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
  geom_node_point(aes(filter = leaf, color = Genus), size = 2)
```

[image]

There is a code in the section *Mapping over searches* on this [blog post](http://www.data-imaginist.com/2017/Introducing-tidygraph/) but it doesn't work on my data and I don't understand why...

```
TBL2 <- TBL %>%
  activate(nodes) %>%
  mutate(Genus = map_bfs_back_chr(node_is_root(), .f = function(node, path, ...) {
    nodes <- .N()
    if (nodes$leaf[node]) return(nodes$Genus[node])
    if (anyNA(unlist(path$result))) return(NA_character_)
    path$result[[1]]
  }))
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: Cannot coerce
>   values to character(1).

**EDIT after Marco Sandri answer**

With `mutate(Genus = as.character(Genus))` there is no more error message but the Genus doesn't propagate correctly. For instance see the third and fourth nodes starting from the right: the parent is supposed to be `NA`... (note that it doesn't work either in the blog post plot).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Genus` in `TBL` is a factor:

```
str(TBL %>% activate(nodes) %>% as_tibble)

# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':       50 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ leaf : logi  FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE ...
# $ Genus: Factor w/ 10 levels "","Citrobacter",..: NA 6 6 NA 6 6 NA NA 6 NA ...
```

but should be a character.
After converting `Genus` from factor to character, the code works.

```
TBL2 <- TBL %>%
  activate(nodes) %>% 
  mutate(Genus = as.character(Genus)) %>%
    mutate(Species = map_bfs_back_chr(node_is_root(), .f = function(node, path, ...) {
        nodes <- .N()
        if (nodes$leaf[node]) return(nodes$Genus[node])
        if (anyNA(unlist(path$result))) return(NA_character_)
        path$result[[1]]
    }))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, the code doesn't work very well, as I said in my edit.

Comment: @MrSnake This is a different and new question. Now the code works but it does not give you the expected result. I suggest you to close (not to delete) this post and to open a new one where you describe in details your problem.